# Could not update ICEauthority file /run/user/1000/ICEauthority when start NoMachine display

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, nomachine

On Ubuntu 20 I made such:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf


blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

to avoid error:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

After rebooting I can't connect to screen by any software.
Nomachine outputs:

```
Cannot detect any display running. Do you want NoMachine to create a new display and proceed to connect to the desktop?
```

Afterwards

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /run/user/1000/ICEauthority
```

Even if it is created with 777 as access it still outputs the messege above.

Video driver is nvidia

The actions from here:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1904811#p1904811
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1936162&sid=083a30ef828b9586b73a0a11a45e3c1e#p1936162

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
sudo aa-complain /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
```

hadn't worked.

How to be able to login to ubuntu 20 using NoMachine and have some human resolution not the awful default 800x600?